# How to ignore highslide script for iDevices?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to apply highslide script ONLY to non iDevice (iPhone, iPad & iPod) devices. How can I simply do this?

here's the code for highslide that I put between head tag:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/highslide/highslide-full.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/highslide/highslide.config.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/highslide/highslide.css" />
```